# How to use a serial attached GPS device with geoclue and PureMaps?

Tags: linux, serial-port, geolocation, gps, gpsd

I have a serial attached GPS device on my Raspberry Pi 4 running the current 64Bit distro. I want to use [PureMaps](https://github.com/rinigus/pure-maps) to navigate.

PureMaps is not detecting any directions and in the C++ files it seems that it uses `geoclue` for position input.

The GPS is working with `gpsd` / `cgps -s` but I do not really understand what I need to do for `geoclue` now.
If I start `geoclue` it shows me in a nearby city (I guess from IP or somewhat) but not from my GPS device. This is then also shown within PureMaps.

**Question**: What do I need to do, to get my GPS location from GPS into `geoclue`?

Comment: Doesn't look like geoclue can directly interface with a serial port GPS device. But maybe you can point geoclue at GPSd. I don't have a GPS device so I cannot test it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it now working with using geoclue + [gps-share](https://github.com/zeenix/gps-share) (GPSd now de-installed):

```
/usr/libexec/geoclue-2.0/demos/agent
./gps-share/gps-share/target/release/gps-share -b 9600 /dev/ttyAMA0
/usr/libexec/geoclue-2.0/demos/where-am-i
```

A little bit strange is still, that I need to run "where-am-i" demo to acutally let deoclue use the gps signal. Without it, it stays using the IP-based location. I do not yet have an solution for this.